# update_post_meta saves data but does not show in Order backend

Tags: order

I want a plugin to add some data into an order with

```
$envios = array (
                 [0] => '990083935372'
                 [1] => 'correos'
                 [2] => 'something...correoschile_etiquetas/990083935372.pdf'
               );
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'tiene_envio',  $envios );
```

The data gets added correctly to DB but it is not showing up in Orders "Customs fields".
[image]

And also get it called correctly by:

```
get_post_meta( $order_id, 'tiene_envio', true );
```

How can I make it appear in Orders "Customs fields"?

[image]

Comment: How do you validate that the data is "correct" in the DB - if it is, the WP admin screen should also show all related post_meta data.

Comment: Are you sure that the correct value (order id) is stored in $order_id?

Comment: @QStudio I updated an Image with the DB information inside wp_postmeta.

Comment: @BorisKuzmanov , yes I have printed all the data and it is correct. I can even call it with get_post_meta

Comment: Can you also locate the lines in the "backend" which are showing the Order screen - so we can see if they are calling the user_meta?

Comment: @QStudio Uploaded

Comment: I'm at a loss, I see no obvious error - so, I'm left with low fruit questions like - are you sure you're viewing the right page in the admin and that the plugin is both active and designed to affect the custom fields area - perhaps you can share more details about what "Orders" are and how they are created...

Comment: @QStudio I just tried adding a different value and with different variable and it was added correctly. So my only guess, is it not possible to add arrays as Customs Order value?

Comment: post_meta can handle single or array values - they are serialized when stored and unserialized when returned - but perhaps the plugin is not designed to handle arrays and is just silently discarding them - you would need to say what plugin you use and try to locate the lines in the plugin which are handling this process.

Comment: @QStudio I applied serialization before adding it to post_meta and worked. It seems you cannot use just arrays into post meta, you need to serialize them or apply json before.